# Can I ask about game-helping tools and software here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I need a spellbook manager. Or some other tool, not really important for the sake of discussion. Can I ask about it on main site? Or would it be off topic? I know software recommendations site, but I doubt that many RPG players will able to see what I ask there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure! Take a look at the [tools](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools) and [online-resources](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-resources) tags to see the kind of questions that have been asked already. [Your question might have been asked and answered already](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=spellbook+%5Btools%5D), and if not you'll get a sense of the detail questions need to have in order to get good Stack Exchange answers. As always: describe the problem you're facing more than the solution you expect, giving more specific detail rather than generalising the question in hopes it'll be more useful to others.

Comment: For good SE question, I think with about 20k rep network-wide I know how it works. I just don't have a good feel what's on-topic here. And I've seen the linked ones, but they are old, and policies do change. Thanks for clarifying this for me :)